# Magento 2 Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value

Tags: error-log, magento2.2.2

After installing Magento 2.2.2 when I check my error log I get this warning.

> Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or
>   decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the
>   temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size:
>   50000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes.

Where the error is saying memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20%. Which temporary table is it referencing to? How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Magento can increase the memory for processing a large amount of data by using memory engines instead of InnoDB. The algorithm increases the memory value for the **max_heap_table_size** and **tmp_table_size** MySQL parameters.

When the allocated memory size for a temporary table will be greater than 20% of **innodb_buffer_pool_size**, the error message is written to the Magento log.

To prevent this error message, you need to update default **Batching configuration** of catalog_category_product (Category Products) indexer because "Current batch size: 100000".

For more details, take a look [here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/optimization/).

Comment: It says we have to change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but it does not explain how!

Comment: Explaining the error is detail but maybe provide a way to correct the issue as well, how was this accepted as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

- Go to your server **`MySQL settings file (my.ini)`**
- Search for **`innodb_buffer_pool_size`** and increase this value.

Comment: where do i locate the mySQL setting file (my.ini)? thanks

Comment: is there a way to config this in project level, and not on mysql?

Answer (score 5):

To determine the optimal [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), run [this query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341/209994) written by [@RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba)

```sql
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;
```

This will give you the RIBPS, Recommended InnoDB Buffer Pool Size, based on all InnoDB Data and Indexes, with an additional 60%.

In my case, the value is `1` (GB), so you have 2 options:

#### A) Configure InnoDB Buffer Pool Size using config file

1. Edit `my.cnf` (MySQL) or `mariadb-server.cnf` (MariaDB), and add one line under the `[mysqld]` section, e.g.:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

2. Restart your MySQL Database

*OR*

#### B) Configure InnoDB Buffer Pool Size Online

`1`GB is `1073741824` bytes. Run the following while logged in as `root`:

```sql
mysqld> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=1073741824;
```

Confirm the new value by running:

```sql
mysqld> SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
```

Answer (score 4):

To prevent this error message, update `innodb_buffer_pool_size` or decrease the batch size value (which decreases memory usage for the temporary table).

Here is an example of the configuration in `app/etc/env.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'indexer' => [
        'batch_size' => [
            'cataloginventory_stock' => [
                'simple' => 200
            ],
            'catalog_category_product' => 666,
            'catalogsearch_fulltext' => [
                'partial_reindex' => 100,
                'mysql_get' => 500,
                'elastic_save' => 500
            ],
            'catalog_product_price' => [
                'simple' => 200,
                'default' => 500,
                'configurable' => 666
            ],
            'catalogpermissions_category' => 999,
            'inventory' => [
                'simple' => 210,
                'default' => 510,
                'configurable' => 616
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Reference: [Indexer optimization](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/indexing/optimization/)

Answer (score 3):

Try to update the value for `batchRowsCount` to `10000` in `{Your_Module_Name}/etc/di.xml` file of `catalog_category_product` (Category Products) indexer `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full`

```
   <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">10000</argument>
            <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Answer (score 3):

The default innodb size is 128MB

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=134217728
```

Edit /etc/my.cnf and overwrite it to 512MB

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=546308096
```

Then restart MySQL. If you are unsure how, just kill it and wait for it to be restarted by your system:

```
killall mysqld
```

Comment: 512MB is `536870912` bytes. 521MB is `546308096` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

For updating the MySQL configuraiton file in my MAC OS Big Sur is in /usr/local/etc/my.cnf, it was installed using brew.

Add line in the my.cnf

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
```

save file and restart mysql using command

```
brew services restart mysql
```

Check if the setting is reflected correctly using this query in MySQL:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_buffer_pool_size%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is at /etc/my.cnf in root SSH, since the full path wasn't noted previously. Upon making any changes to /etc/my.cnf file, please restart MySQL for those changes to take effect

Answer (score 0):

- Search your my.cnf file by executing `locate my.cnf` (mine is under /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
- Edit this file
- Search for **`innodb_buffer_pool_size`**. If it does not exist then create it, e.g.

  `innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M`
- Restart the mysql service `sudo service mysql restart`