# magento 2 main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: magento2

**I have Magento 2.3.1 on digitalocean plesk panel**

**It shows error like bellow**

> [2019-04-22 11:36:49] main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the
>   temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please
>   update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which
>   decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size:
>   100000; Allocated memory size: 130000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool
>   size: 134217728 bytes. [] []

Comment: Please check if this link is useful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207457/magento-2-please-update-innodb-buffer-pool-size-or-decrease-batch-size-value

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem with Category Products index. In custom module in `etc/di.xml` decrease the number for `batchRowsCount`.

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Action\Full">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="configurable" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

More details [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html).

Comment: May i know which path?

Comment: Full path is vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc