# Magento 2.3 - Theme Configuration mismatch after migration completed from magento 1.9 multi store website?

Tags: migration, magento2.3.4, data-migration, memory

After migration, my multi-store website to Magento 2.3.4 **Back-end working good all data migrated successfully** my theme completely collapsed getting following error,

Following are my errors after migration,

**Frond-end error:**

1) https://snipboard.io/Dw47EM.jpg

2) https://snipboard.io/uIhnAJ.jpg

**System.log:**

https://justpaste.it/5ry3a

**Debug.log:**

https://justpaste.it/42t47

Try lots of combinations to solve the issue, still facing the issue.

`Server details`: Localhost - Centos 7, Nginx, Magento 2.3.4, paid theme (http://www.codazon.com/document/fastest/magento2/index.html)

Comment: Check this post for system log error: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207457/magento-2-please-update-innodb-buffer-pool-size-or-decrease-batch-size-value

Comment: From the above link => "To prevent this error message, you need to update default Batching configuration of catalog_category_product (Category Products) indexer because "Current batch size: 100000"."  Where i can update the batch size?

Comment: Please check here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html

Comment: Current my value is 100000. Path => root_folder -> vendor -> magento -> module_catalog -> etc -> di.xml line no. 1056    code =>     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">100000</argument>
            <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> What value i need to assign here?

Comment: please check the answer if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module's {Your_Module_Name}/etc/di.xml file, decrease the value for `batchRowsCount` to `10000`

> catalog_category_product (Category Products)
>
> Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml
>
> Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full

```
   <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">10000</argument>
            <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Please read more [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Does my path is right =>  root_folder -> vendor -> magento -> module_catalog -> etc -> di.xml?

Comment: Path: /magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml

Comment: After that shall i run all the commands ( https://bit.ly/3cRykXn ) or specific commands only?

Comment: Yes try to run the commands and check if works!

Comment: After above correction my system.log => https://justpaste.it/4zc1e debug.log => https://justpaste.it/2l866

Comment: Not sure about it but check this link if it helps: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/452#issuecomment-419663688

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109113/discussion-between-zus-and-bhaumik-1987).

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: After above correction my system.log => https://justpaste.it/4zc1e debug.log => https://justpaste.it/2l866

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109159/discussion-between-zus-and-bhaumik-1987).